# How to create dummy view to anchor popup window android

Tags: java, android, view, popupwindow

I have the following situation:

```
private void startConnection() {
    HashMap<String,String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
    hm.put("email","email@example.com");
    String URL = "192.168.1.2/test.php";
    Db_connection db = new Db_connection(hm,URL,context);
    db.startTest();
}

public class Db_connection {

    private HashMap<String, String> params;
    private String URL;
    private ConnectionController CC;
    private ToolTip tt;
    private Context con;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public Db_connection(HashMap<String,String> params,String URL,Context con) {
        this.params = params;
        this.URL = URL;
        this.con = con;
        this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(con);
        this.dialog.setCancelable(true);
        this.CC = ConnectionController.getInstance();
    }

    public void startTest() {
        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, new JSONObject(params),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                if (dialog.isShowing()) { dialog.dismiss(); }

                if (response != null && response.has("result")) {
                    try {
                        if (!response.getString("result").matches("error")) {
                            Toast.makeText(con, "Response: "+response.getString("result"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else { Toast.makeText(con, response.getString("errmsg"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); return; }

                        VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                ToolTip tt = new ToolTip(con, error.getMessage());
                tt.showNow();
                Log.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
            }
        });
        req.setRetryPolicy(rp);
        CC.addToRequestQueue(req);
    }
}

public class ToolTip {

private Context con;
private PopupWindow pn;
private View layout;
private ImageView cancel;
private TextView mess;

public ToolTip(Context con,String htmlMsg) {
    this.con = con;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)con.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tooltip,null);
    pn = new PopupWindow(layout,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,false);
    pn.setAnimationStyle(R.style.AnimationToolTip);
    cancel = (ImageView)layout.findViewById(R.id.tooltip_imageClose);
    mess = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.tooltip_mainText);
        mess.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlMsg));

        cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pn.dismiss();
        }
        });
    }

    public void showNow() {
        pn.showAtLocation(/*HERE IS WHERE I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO PASS AS VIEW*/((Activity) con).getActionBar().getCustomView(), Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 180);
    }
}
```

Everything works but when the volley request throws an error and uses the ToolTip class to show the error:

```
ToolTip tt = new ToolTip(con, error.getMessage());
tt.showNow();
```

i get this exception:

```
11-21 15:08:06.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22448): Process: com.tooltip.test, PID: 22448
11-21 15:08:06.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22448): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.tooltip.test.ConnectionController cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
11-21 15:08:06.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22448):    at com.tooltip.test.ToolTip.showNow(ToolTip.java:46)
11-21 15:08:06.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22448):    at com.tooltip.test.Db_connection$2.onErrorResponse(Db_connection.java:100)
11-21 15:08:06.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22448):    at com.android.volley.Request.deliverError(Request.java:577)
11-21 15:08:06.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22448):    at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:101)
11-21 15:08:06.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22448):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-21 15:08:06.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22448):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-21 15:08:06.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22448):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-21 15:08:06.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22448):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5139)
11-21 15:08:06.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22448):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-21 15:08:06.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22448):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-21 15:08:06.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22448):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
11-21 15:08:06.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22448):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
11-21 15:08:06.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22448):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Usually i pass this:

```
((Activity) con).getActionBar().getCustomView()
```

as the view to which anchor the popup window and it works but in this particular case, the activity calling the tooltip class, doesn't have an actionbar (it's the only one, all others activity does have the custom actionbar).

I'm here to ask if there is a method to use a dummy, programmatically created view to use in this case.

Or maybe i'm doing it wrong and you have a nice suggestion :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some try i finally came to a solution: i choose to use two different method, one for activity with action bar, and one for activity without action bar:

```
public void showNow() { //THIS IS FOR ACTIVITY WITH ACTION BAR
    pn.showAtLocation((Activity)con.getActionBar().getCustomView(), Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 180);
}

public void showNowNoActBar() { //THIS IS FOR ACTIVITY WITHOUT ACTION BAR
    pn.showAtLocation(con.findViewById(R.id.dummy_hidden_view), Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 180);
}
```

Obviously `R.id.dummy_hidden_view` is defined in the XML Layout of the activity without the custom action bar like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dummy_hidden_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

I think that both method could be solved with only one method but as of now, i can rely on my "double method" solution for what i need. Hope it helps someone else. Still remain the fact that i will appreciate any better suggestion on how to handle this.